# Example(s) of iPhone apps, with Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: ios, admob, ads

I spent some time simply looking for ...

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios

... some examples of iPhone / iPad apps (I mean -- actually in the apple App Store)

which use Google Mobile Ads SDK

(whether AdMob or AdSense.)

After googling and googling I really can't find any. Are there any?

Comment: Did you find your solution.

Comment: Just waiting to see if more people can send more examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of app which uses Google Ad in their app:

1. [jDisk](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/jdisk-convert-your-device/id604793088?mt=8)
2. [Totem-Smash](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/totem-smash/id903506713?mt=8)
3. [Don't touch the spikes](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/dont-touch-the-spikes/id895942435?mt=8)